# Problems with MinGW g++ and eclipse with CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, gcc

Background Info: I am running Eclipse Mars and Windows 10
I'm going to list out all the steps I've taken so far:

- Download MinGW

  - Install MSYS installation for MinGW Developers (I don't think I needed this?)
  - Install mingw32-base
  - Install mingw32-base
  - Install mingw32-gcc-g++
  - Install msys-base (Don't think I needed this either)
- Add MINGW_HOME Environment Variable and MINGW_HOME\bin to Path.
- Check versions of gcc, g++, and gdb (all showed they were successfully installed)

However, when I open Eclipse I get two errors indicating that g++ and gcc are not in my Path.
How do I fix or get around these errors?

Comment: Are there `mingw32-gcc.exe`, `mingw32-g++.exe`, `mingw32-make.exe` in `%MINGW_HOME%\bin`?

Comment: Try setting the path variable in "Run/Run Configurations.../Environment". This did it for me on OS X, since Eclipse was not reading the `PATH` UNIX variable set in my profile. Not 100% if that's the cause in Windows, but may give it a try.

Comment: Yep, mingw32-gcc.exe, mingw32-g++.exe, mingw32-make.exe are in there.

Comment: not to take off topic but you might want to consider the mingw-w64 team g++, as the 'original' (used loosly) is missing some features, and starting to get a bit out of date. on top of that, is the folder `%MINGW_HOME%\bin` as used (that may not actually evaluate?) in your path, rather than links to the actual files themselves?